# Added get it dependency. IDE gave version solving error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

Because every version of integration_test from sdk depends on collection 1.15.0-nullsafety.5 and get_it >=6.0.0 depends on collection ^1.15.0, integration_test from sdk is incompatible with get_it >=6.0.0.
So, because mcuapp depends on both get_it ^6.0.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because mcuapp depends on both get_it ^6.0.0 and integration_test any from sdk, version solving failed.)
Process finished with exit code 1

Note: I had recently upgraded Dart and flutter

Comment: Have you checked [this article](https://pratikbutani.medium.com/flutter-2-upgrade-flutter-version-solving-failed-error-33ac1087cb6b)

Comment: try using get_it: , without any version number

Comment: @FarrukhSajjad tried it. Pub get ran with exit code 0. How does this work without a version number?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the version int the pubspec.yaml and replace it with `any`.
This however might break code, since it will use an other version of the package. In some cases some packages are not compatible with other packages at all

Answer (score 0):

Update all dependencies from pubspec.yaml file because some of your updated dependencies and depending on old version dependencies. Just

> Go to [pub.dev][1] > search your dependencies > copy updated version to `pubspec.yaml` file > run `flutter pub get` > `flutter pub upgrade`
> [1]: https://pub.dev/

Comment: The issue isn't with updating dependency. The issue is flutter 2 not working with dependency.

Comment: I got this error when i update dependencies. So I simple switched to older version because in flutter some dependencies and dependent on other dependencies. And I resolved this error by simply switch to older version of dependency. So I thought maybe this will help you.